# 2 GroupJoin's in a single query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have a query like this that joins two entities together:

```
IEnumerable<ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel> query =
ICDUnitOfWork.AlphaGroups.Find().GroupJoin(ICDUnitOfWork.Alphas.Find(),
                                           a => a.AlphaGroupID,
                                           g => g.AlphaGroupID,
                                           (alphaGroups, alphas) =>
                                           new ICD.ViewModels.HomeSearchViewModel
                                           {
                                               AlphaGroups =
                                                   alphaGroups,
                                               Alphas = alphas,
                                               SearchTerm = searchTerm
                                           }).OrderBy(x => x.AlphaGroups.Title);
```

I need to join the Alphas entity with another Entity called "Codes".  Is it possible to do this in a single query, or should I break this out into 2 separate queries?

Answer (score 1):

A standard entity framework query would look more like:

```
var query =
  from a in dbContext.Alphas
  from g in a.AlphaGroups
  from c in a.Codes
  select new {Alpha = a, AlphaGroup = g, Code = c}
```

Or perhaps:

```
var query =
  dbContext.Alphas.Include("AlphaGroups").Include("Codes");
```

Why does your query look so bad?

Comment: My query is bad and I should feel bad?

Comment: Don't feel bad.  Do be open to more ways to bring in additional tables.  The question doesn't make it the relationships clear enough between the tables to choose between those ways.  I can't recommend GroupJoin based on the information presented.